# Why return node.next will return the whole linked list?

Tags: python-3.x, merge, linked-list, array-merge

I am new to coding and am working on LeetCode#21 Merge two sorted list.

An example:
Input: list1 = [1,2,4], list2 = [1,3,4]
Output: [1,1,2,3,4,4]

A common solution to this question is:

```
    class ListNode:
        def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
            self.val = val
            self.next = next

    class Solution:
        def mergeTwoLists(self, list1: ListNode, list2: ListNode) -> ListNode:
            dummy = ListNode()
            tail = dummy

            while list1 and list2:
                 if list1.val < list2.val:
                    tail.next = list1
                    list1 = list1.next
                 else:
                    tail.next = list2
                    list2 = list2.next
                 tail = tail.next

            if list1:
                 tail.next = list1
            elif list2:
                 tail.next = list2

            return dummy.next
```

I am confused with the last line: return dummy.next

Shouldn't it simply return the next node of dummy node?
How will that return the whole list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dummy is created as a temporary head, because at the start we don't know whether our head starts with list1 or list2.

After we are done merging, dummy will look like this. The dummy value is 0 because this is the default value when you call `ListNode()`.

```
0 > 1 > 1 > 2 > 3 > 4 > 4
```

But our original list does not have 0, therefore 0 is removed by `dummy.next`

dummy.next will look like this.

```
1 > 1 > 2 > 3 > 4 > 4
```

This will return the whole list because each ListNode stores its `next` value in the `self.next` property.

You can check with this. We know we have reached the end node of the linked list when its `self.next` is None.

```
current = dummy.next;
while current is not None:
    print(current.val);
    current = current.next;
```

Comment: Thank you! I just realized the question is asking for the head of the node... That's why they only return one node. Here is the original Question: "You are given the heads of two sorted linked lists list1 and list2.

Merge the two lists in a one sorted list. The list should be made by splicing together the nodes of the first two lists.

Return the head of the merged linked list." Thank you very much tho for explaining the concept!

Comment: Welcome! Does this answer your question? Can please help accept the answer, thanks!